# Two jquery items not working together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I am trying to jquery isotope and Balkin Style portfolio to work together (http://codepen.io/MightyShaban/pen/eGaCf) buti cant. I can get them to work perfectly on there own but once together it wont work.  I have also tried noConflict() with no luck as well. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

JS Code.

```
    // Balkin   
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('.portfolio ul li a').click(function() {
     var itemID = $(this).attr('href');
     $('.portfolio ul').addClass('item_open');
     $(itemID).addClass('item_open');
     return false;
 });
 $('.close').click(function() {
     $('.port, .portfolio ul').removeClass('item_open');
     return false;
 });

 $(".portfolio ul li a").click(function() {
     $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: parseInt($("#top").offset().top)
     }, 400);
 });

 });

        /*===========================================================*/
    /*  Isotope Posrtfolio
    /*===========================================================*/     
    if(jQuery.isFunction(jQuery.fn.isotope)){
        jQuery('.portfolio_list').isotope({
            itemSelector : '.list_item',
            layoutMode : 'fitRows',
            animationEngine : 'jquery'
        });

    /* ---- Filtering ----- */
        jQuery('#filter li').click(function(){
            var $this = jQuery(this);
            if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
                return false;
            } else {
                    jQuery('#filter .selected').removeClass('selected');
                    var selector = $this.attr('data-filter');
                    $this.parent().next().isotope({ filter: selector });
                    $this.addClass('selected');
                    return false;
                }
        }); 
    }
```

HTML (needs to be made more tidy i know, sorry)

```
<!--Portfolio-->
<section id="portfolio" class="portfolio">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row"> 
      <!--begin isotope -->
      <div class="isotope"> 
        <!--begin portfolio filter -->
        <ul id="filter" class="option-set clearfix">
          <li data-filter="*" class="selected"><a href="#">All</a></li>
          <li data-filter=".responsive"><a href="#">Responsive</a></li>
          <li data-filter=".mobile"><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
          <li data-filter=".branding"><a href="#">Branding</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!--end portfolio filter --> 

        <!--begin portfolio_list -->
        <ul id="list" class="portfolio_list">
          <!--begin span4 -->
          <li class="list_item col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 responsive"><a href="#item02">
            <div class="view view-first"> <img src="../overlay/images/photos/project_1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Title Goes Here"> <div class="mask"> <div class="portfolio_details zoom"><h2>Nostrum mnesarchum</h2>
              <span>Art / Illustration</span></div> </div> </div></a>
          </li>
          <!--end span4 -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the second jQuery item in a separate `$( document ).ready(function() {});`, and you should be fine.

You might even want to put it in a whole different set of `<script></script>` tags too.

Comment: It didnt work sorry. Thank you for your quick reply though. I put it up on jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Stratos123/7tef5ckj/ the isotope wont work but if you click on the image the drop down works. But if you remove code for Balkin the isotope does work.

Comment: Humm, I'm not too sure to be honest. Have you tried `jQuery` in place of the shorthand `$` selector?

Comment: Yeah, thanks for trying. If anyone else has any ideas please let me know and check out my fiddle.